# How to add text to python calculation?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, command-line, formatting

I'm trying to create this with the help of python:

in a for loop (from 1,10)

```
text i+(i*(i+2.5)) text [i+(i*(i+2.5))] text
```

results:

```
text 1+(1*(1+2.5) text 4.5 text
text 2+(2*(2+2.5) text 11 text
text 3+(3*(3+2.5) text 19.5 text
etc
```

- Every `i` must have a different formatting
- All code must be in one commandline

This is what I have created

```
python -c "import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ''); print('\n'.join(locale.format('\%.1f',i+(i*(i+2.5))) for i in range(1,10,1)))"
```

How can add the rest of the text?

**UPDATE**:

With the help of Tanmaya Meher's answer I created this command:

```
python -c "import sys,locale; [sys.stdout.write('text1 ' + '\%.2f+(\%.2f*(\%.2f+2.5))'\%(i,i,i) +' text2 ' + '\%.2f'\%(i+(i*(i+2.5))) + ' text3' + '\n') for i in range(1,11,1)]"
```

but I still don't know where to place local formatting (locale)

Comment: Why do you want it in one command line? You should use a script for that.

Comment: I need a commandline to use it as an external command in my texteditor (vim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help. Please specify if anything need to be added

```
python -c "import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ''); print ('\n'.join('text1 ' + locale.format_string('%.1f+(%.1f*(%.1f+2.5))',(i,i,i), grouping = True)  + ' text2 ' + locale.format_string('%.1f',i+(i*(i+2.5)), grouping = True) + ' text3'for i in range(1,1111)))"
```

Output:

```
text1 1.0+(1.0*(1.0+2.5)) text2 4.5 text3
text1 2.0+(2.0*(2.0+2.5)) text2 11.0 text3
text1 3.0+(3.0*(3.0+2.5)) text2 19.5 text3
text1 4.0+(4.0*(4.0+2.5)) text2 30.0 text3
text1 5.0+(5.0*(5.0+2.5)) text2 42.5 text3
text1 6.0+(6.0*(6.0+2.5)) text2 57.0 text3
text1 7.0+(7.0*(7.0+2.5)) text2 73.5 text3
text1 8.0+(8.0*(8.0+2.5)) text2 92.0 text3
text1 9.0+(9.0*(9.0+2.5)) text2 112.5 text3
text1 10.0+(10.0*(10.0+2.5)) text2 135.0 text3
...
...
text1 1,109.0+(1,109.0*(1,109.0+2.5)) text2 12,33,762.5 text3
text1 1,110.0+(1,110.0*(1,110.0+2.5)) text2 12,35,985.0 text3
```

If you don't want grouping, i.e., `12,35,985.0` format (with commas); then just remove `grouping = True` from the code.

Comment: This would be a good solution if I'm enable to use locale formatting.

Comment: This works also but I still don't know where to place the local formatting: `python -c "import sys,locale; [sys.stdout.write('text1 ' + '\%.2f+(\%.2f*(\%.2f+2.5))'\%(i,i,i) +' text2 ' + '\%.2f'\%(i+(i*(i+2.5))) + ' text3' + '\n') for i in range(1,11,1)]"` (I update my question)

Comment: sorry for late reply.:) Just look at the updated code I have edited and saved according to your criteria.

Comment: See the updated code. Just placed text to be displayed and formatting and the for loop inside the `join`.

Comment: Almost the solution, wow! :) The first three `i` still have no local formatting. Do I have to place every `%.1f` within a format() box and every `'('`, `'))'` and `'+'` within quotes?

Comment: I think you have to as you are trying to print a string with some formatting. See the updated code with complete locale formatting.

Comment: No, its not allowed. :) See the updated one with complete locale formatting and grouping if you want that. If not just remove `grouping = True` from code.